bash read, trap INT, ctrl/c, bash autocomplete limited to working directory
Below is a script that I created to demonstrate a problem with Bash autocomplete. The problem occurs after pressing CTRL/C inside READ and TRAP function INT.
After pressing CTRL/C, Bash autocomplete only works for files in the current directory. I do have the current directory in my PATH variable among the usual /sbin /bin/ usr/bin, etc. I also checked the output of "shopt" and "set" in the shell before and after experiencing the issue, but I don't see the difference.
This is a custom Linux (4.20 and 5.9), running bash 4.4.
#!/bin/bash

$( return 0 2>&- )
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "Source-execution required. Aborted"
  exit 1
fi


doit=doit

cleanup()
{
  trap - INT
  echo; echo "doing all sorts of stuff to unset vars, etc."
  unset doit # Abandon further processing.
  unset cleanup
}

ctrl_c()
{
  echo; echo
  echo "Canceled."
  cleanup
}

trap "ctrl_c; return" INT
read -r -e -n 1 -p "?" 

if [[ "${doit}" ]]; then
  echo "you won't see this after ctrl/c"
  cleanup
fi

Output is as following:
# gr<tab>
grep       groups     grubed     grubed.sh  


# source xx.sh 
?^C

Canceled.

doing all sorts of stuff to unset vars, etc.

# gr<tab>  -> resolves right into grubed.sh which is in the current directory. 


Does it go back to normal if you press Ctrl+C again?

When I press CTRL/C nothing appears on screen. But when I first press RETURN, then CTRC/C prints the typical ^C and then TAB completion works normal again. So the the sequence is RETURN, CTRL/C.

I just found out that the same issue also exists without the trap command. So just using the read command in the sourced script triggers the problem. The script must be source executed, however, to reproduce the problem.

Yes, it must be a bug in bash. Consider reporting it at bug-bash@gnu.org

The problem seems to be caused by the combination of two things :

return in:

trap "ctrl_c; return" INT


-e in:

read -r -e -n 1 -p "?" 

If you remove any of the two, the problem does not occur.

I can't remove the return from the trap command, otherwise the script will hang when pressing CTRL/C. I'm pretty sure I tried with -e, but probably before I discovered I needed that trap return. Anyway, as far as I can tell, removing -e solved the issue. How silly. Thanks a lot!

Out of curiosity, why do you need return ?

It's necessary after pressing CTRL/C, otherwise it requires to press a key to get the command prompt back.
